# FindDistributionParameters for a ParameterMixtureDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

Let's say I define a simple hierarchical model as follows (I don't actually particularly care about the distributions chosen):

```
modelDist = ParameterMixtureDistribution[NormalDistribution[a, 1], 
a \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[b, 1], Assumptions -> b > 0]
```

I then generate `vals`, a list of random samples from a version of this distribution where the true value of `b` is 2.

If I do

```
FindDistributionParameters[vals, 
 ParameterMixtureDistribution[NormalDistribution[a, 1], 
  a \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[b, 1], Assumptions -> b > 0]]
```

I get error messages from `NMaximize` that suggest it's trying to fit both `b` and `a`, even though `a` is just a dummy variable. If I provide an initial value for `b`,

```
FindDistributionParameters[vals, 
 ParameterMixtureDistribution[NormalDistribution[a, 1], 
  a \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[b, 1], 
  Assumptions -> b > 0], {{b, 1.}}]
```

I get the message

```
FindDistributionParameters::prms: The parameters to be estimated in ParameterMixtureDistribution[NormalDistribution[a,1],a\[Distributed]GammaDistribution[b,1],Assumptions->b>0] are not the same as the parameters in {{b,1.}}.
```

Is there a way to make this work? Specifically, is there a way to get `FindDistributionParameters` to recognize that `a` isn't actually a parameter that needs to be fit? Perhaps some kind of symbol manipulation or evaluation tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work by deleting the `Assumptions` on `b`:

```
FindDistributionParameters[
    vals, 
    ParameterMixtureDistribution[
       NormalDistribution[a, 1], 
       a \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[b, 1]
    ]
]
```